# How to access array variable value in the child view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to access an array defined as property on the parent view from child view and I get an empty array. here is what I did. could someone shed some light please!

FirstTableViewController.h

```
@interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *SomeItems; 
@end
```

in my FirstTableViewController.m.  I have code that initialized the SomeItems with values. This has been verified

On the FirstTableViewController view there is a button that displays a second SecondTableView

in SecondTableViewController.m I have

```
#import "FirstTableViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
FirstTableViewController * objParent;   
NSLog(@"count = %i",[objParent.SomeItems count]);  //this return 0
}
```

thanks in advance!

EDITED

ToDoListTableViewController.h

```
@interface ToDoListTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue : (id) sender;
@end
```

---

ToDoListTableViewController.m

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//Attempt to pass toDoItems to new view controller.
//CompleteTableViewController.toDoItems = [self.toDoItems copy]; //this line caused compiler error saying toDoItems not found on object of CompleteTableViewController

CompleteTableViewController * objChild =  (CompleteTableViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
if(objChild != nil)
objChild.toDoItems = [self.toDoItems copy];

//sorry for weird code, as I don't really understand how this method really works.
//but I have a feeling I am just some inches away from getting it to work the way i want
}
```

---

CompleteTableViewController.h

```
@interface CompleteTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
@end
```

---

CompleteTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"#%i record(s) in Complete Table View", [toDoItems count]);
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: your `objParent` looks to be `nil`, what do you expect from a `nil` pointer anyway?

Comment: yeah, I posted that by mistake but in my actual code I did have: FirstTableViewController * objParent;   FirstTableViewController * objParent = [[FirstTableViewController alloc]init];  - thanks!

Comment: @HailNguyen, it does not make the things better, because you would just create another instance of the class, which is independent from the real parent one which you'd like to access to.

Comment: @holex, I guess I have to agree which you on this. but since this is not the main issue I am trying to solve. You can dismiss this issue of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that you miss the basilar concept of the OOP.

You declared this:

```
FirstTableViewController * objParent;
```

but first of all **it is not initializated** and second **it doesn't point to your instanced viewController**.

Other things but that at this point become secondary are:

if you are using `ARC`, declare the `property` `strong` instead of `retain`;
method and variable should respect the `Camel` methodology so is not `SomeItems` but is `someItems`;

So if you are opening a viewController from another and you want access to that `array`, the best thing that you could do is pass that `array` and so have a property like this also in the second viewController:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSArray *someItems;
```

and when you press the button in the first viewController, before push the second viewController:

```
secondViewController.someItems = [self.someItems copy];
```

**Note that in the second view controller the array is not mutable, because probably you want just access to the informations. But this depend from you.**

Is a little bit hard explain you more because i see that you are really a newbie. But, i hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. so secondViewController.someItems = [self.someItems copy]; should live in prepareForSegue method?

Comment: If you are using Storyboard yes. Please set my answer as right if you are satisfied. Thanks

Comment: I certainly will. I did what you suggest but I still couldn't get it to pass the array value to popup view

Comment: paste your new code please..edit your post putting EDIT: at the end

Comment: I just edited original post with updated code - thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: First of all set NSArray and not NSMutableArray in the CompleteTableViewController because you are passing a copy that is immutable. Second, you the code seems correct so if you don't have nothing means that your actual array is nil and so the problem is in the part of code where you fill the array.

Comment: I actually plan to alter contents of the array in the CompleteTableViewController that is the reason I used NSMutableArray. Knowing changes will not being updated on the original array on the parent view, but that is ok for what I am trying to do. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference for the parent object through to the child on creation, or simply pass a reference to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

From Matteo suggestion, this seems to solve my issue

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    CompleteTableViewController *objChild = (CompleteTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

        if(objChild != nil){
            objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems copy];
        }
}
```

thanks Matteo.

Answer (score -1):

In the `SecondTableViewController`, you've declared the `FirstTableViewController` in `viewDidLoad`, but that does not mean it's pointing to your previously created `FirstTableViewController` (you've made no assignment). Before `viewDidLoad` is called, you need to pass the `FirstTableViewController` to the `SecondTableViewController`, assign it to a variable that's not local in scope, and then you can access the `FirstTableViewController` and/or its `SomeItems` inside `viewDidLoad`.

Without knowing more of your design or what you're trying to accomplish, it'd be best to pass `SomeItems` to `SecondTableViewController` as part of initializing it if that's all you need from `FirstTableViewController`. If the state of what you're accessing is going to change as you are going from controller to controller, I'd highly recommend you spend more time reading up on Model-View-Controller (MVC), delegation and possibly Key-Value Observation (KVO). You're missing some fundamental knowledge.

Edit: also agree on naming, `SomeItems` should be `someItems`.

Comment: that is not nice to down vote. but let take it easy people! not everyone is trying to be iOS apps genius here, well maybe some days they will. but it is not necessary to tell people "hey you are dump!" just because they didn't understand how to do things..please! you can help please do, otherwise move on your way!